# Duda en el codigo-Recorrido por Amplitud (Grafos)-No recorre - Java

Tags: java, algoritmos, java-8

Lo que sucede es que tengo un problema en mi codigo. Este trata sobre el recorrido por amplitud de un grafo. Lo que sucede es que uno de los vertices no encola y por ende no me sale el resultado que se pide. Quiero saber cuál es mi error y cómo corregirlo.

De antemano, agradezco su atención.

El grafo es el siguiente:

[image]

Mi código está escrito en Java y tengo las clases NodoG (que representa el nodo del grafo), Grafo (que representa el grafo) y Principal (donde hago las operaciones).

Además, yo no tomo en cuenta los pesos de las aristas, solo considero el orden que se introducen los adyacentes en el nodo respectivo.

Por ejemplo:

- 1->2 con peso 3: Lo escribo primero al introducir los datos
- 1->4 con peso 10: lo pongo segundo
- 1->5 con peso 12: lo pongo tercero

Y así lo hago con cada nodo. En caso no haya adyacentes para un nodo, entonces no lo escribo como dato.

Me sale así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando debe ser:

> 1->2->4->5->3

A continuacion muestro mi codigo:

Clase NodoG

```
    public class NodoG {
    private int dato;
    boolean visitado;
    List<NodoG> adyacentes;

    public NodoG(int dato){
        this.dato = dato;
        this.visitado = false;
        this.adyacentes = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public int getDato() {
        return dato;
    }

    public void setDato(int dato) {
        this.dato = dato;
    }

    public boolean isVisitado() {
        return visitado;
    }

    public void setVisitado(boolean visitado) {
        this.visitado = visitado;
    }

    public List<NodoG> getAdyacentes() {
        return adyacentes;
    }

    public void setAdyacentes(ArrayList<NodoG> adyacentes) {
        this.adyacentes = adyacentes;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return (dato + "->");
    } 
 }
```

Clase Grafo

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grafo {
    private List<NodoG> nodoGrafo;
    
    public Grafo(){
        nodoGrafo = new ArrayList<NodoG>();
    }

    public List<NodoG> getNodoGrafo() {
        return nodoGrafo;
    }

    public void setNodoGrafo(ArrayList<NodoG> nodoGrafo) {
        this.nodoGrafo = nodoGrafo;
    }
    
    public void insertarNodoG(){
        System.out.println("Inserte dato: ");
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("->");
        int valor = entrada.nextInt();
        NodoG nodo = new NodoG(valor);
        nodoGrafo.add(nodo);       
    }
    
    public NodoG buscarNodoGrafo(int n1){
        NodoG nodo = null;
        for (NodoG nodoGrafo1 : nodoGrafo) {
            if(nodoGrafo1.getDato() == n1){
                nodo = nodoGrafo1;
            }
        }
        return nodo;
    }
    
    public void insertarAdyacente(){
        System.out.println("Insertar dato del nodo del grafo: ");
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("->");
        int valor = entrada.nextInt();
        NodoG nodo = buscarNodoGrafo(valor);
        if(nodo!=null){
            System.out.println("Insertar dato del adyacente: ");
            System.out.print("->");
            int dato = entrada.nextInt();
            NodoG nuevo = new NodoG(dato);
            nodo.getAdyacentes().add(nuevo);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("->Nodo no existe en el grafo.");
        }
    }
    
    public void busquedaAmplitud(){
        System.out.println("Inserte nodo inicial: ");
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int dato = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        NodoG inicio = buscarNodoGrafo(dato);
        if(inicio!=null){
            Queue<NodoG> cola = new LinkedList<NodoG>();
            
            cola.add(inicio);
            inicio.setVisitado(true);
            while(!cola.isEmpty()){
              //  System.out.println("tamanio: "+cola.size());
                NodoG elem = cola.poll();
                //System.out.println("--------------");
                System.out.print("->" + elem.getDato());
                //System.out.println("--------------");
                List<NodoG> ady = elem.getAdyacentes();
                for (int i = 0;i<ady.size();i++) {
                    NodoG ady1 = ady.get(i);
                    if(ady1!= null && !ady1.isVisitado()){
                        cola.add(ady1);
                        ady1.setVisitado(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("El nodo no existe en el grafo");
        }
    }

}
```

Clase Principal

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Grafo G = new Grafo();
        int opc;
        System.out.println("=========================");
        System.out.println("RECORRIDO POR AMPLITUD");
        System.out.println("=========================");
        System.out.println("¿Cuanto nodos tiene el arbol?: ");
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cant = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("---------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Ingrese los valores de los nodos: ");
        for(int i=0;i<cant;i++){
            G.insertarNodoG();
        }
        System.out.println("==================================");
        System.out.println("Adyacentes de los nodos");
        System.out.println("===================================");
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese el nodo que desea ingresar los adyacentes");
            G.insertarAdyacente();
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
            System.out.print("¿Desea ingresar otro adyacente?: (Si: 1) (No: Cualquier numero) -> ");
            opc = entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        }while(opc == 1);
        do{
            System.out.println("==========================");
            System.out.println("Recorrido por Amplitud: ");
            System.out.println("---------------------------");
            G.busquedaAmplitud();
            System.out.println("\n---------------------------");     
            System.out.println("¿Desea hacer otro recorrido? (Si: 1) (No: Cualquier numero)->");
            opc = entrada.nextInt();
        }while(opc==1);
    }
}
```

Agradeceré mucho su ayuda.